# ASP.NET Hidden Field Value not modified on callback

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, callback, hidden-field

I'm changing the value of an asp:HiddenField during callback.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenField" Value="old value" />

private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (IsCallBack)
   {
      hiddenField.Value = "new value";
   }
}
```

but after the callback, the value of the hidden field is "old value". When debugging, I can see that the value of the hidden field is "new value". I would like to know why it is retaining the original value. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `IsPostBack`? Are `UpdatePanels` involved?

Comment: It is `IsCallBack`, I don't have any `UpdatePanels` involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to change the value of the Hidden Field in Async/partial post back but your Hidden field is not in the update panel.

**Edit:** You need to put your hidden field in the update panel.

Comment: Yup, my hidden field is not inside an Update Panel. Should I put it inside an Update panel?

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way instead of using UpdatePanel?

Comment: You need to understand the theory of Partial postback. Values will only be updated in async postback when these are in updatepanel. If you are really want to update value on server side, then there is no other way. Other way if you don't want to add update panel, you can do it in javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I already thought of updating it using javascript... I'm also searching on how to invoke javascript functions from code-behind w/o using the `RegisterClientScriptBlock` method and the WebBrowser one.. (it will affect my project's trust level). Anyways thank you very much! This is helpful :)